# Simple colums in editor

Tags: layout, page, static-content, column

the best way to create column in the editor is?
I try to create  with Bootstrap class but, it's not working...

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the table creating tool located right after the eraser tool. The bootsrap design will not be visible inside the editor since it does not load any external CSS nor script.